# Node.js - sending files to client using sendFile

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am very new to Node.js and have been following a game-making tutorial, found here: http://rawkes.com/articles/creating-a-real-time-multiplayer-game-with-websockets-and-node.html

I am trying to improve on the game detailed in the tutorial by sending all the necessary files to the client.

When I connect to my server as a client, this error is thrown in the server terminal,

```html
_http_outgoing.js:344
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
    ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:344:11)
    at Array.write (/Users/Mark/node_modules/express/node_modules/finalhandler/index.js:164:9)
    at listener (/Users/Mark/node_modules/express/node_modules/on-finished/index.js:169:15)
    at onFinish (/Users/Mark/node_modules/express/node_modules/on-finished/index.js:100:5)
    at callback (/Users/Mark/node_modules/express/node_modules/on-finished/node_modules/ee-first/index.js:55:10)
    at IncomingMessage.onevent (/Users/Mark/node_modules/express/node_modules/on-finished/node_modules/ee-first/index.js:93:5)
    at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:921:12)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:442:9)
```

Here is the offending code:

```html
var util = require("util"),
    Player = require("./Player").Player;

var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http');
var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(8000)
var io = require('socket.io');


var socket,
    players;
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/js/game.js');
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/js/Keys.js');
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/js/Player.js');
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/js/requestAnimationFrame.js');
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/style/game.css');
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/style/reset.css');
});
function init() {
    players = [];
    socket = io.listen(httpServer)
   
    //streamline
    socket.configure(function() {
    socket.set("transports", ["websocket"]);
    socket.set("log level", 2);
});
    
    
    setEventHandlers()
    
}


init()
```

Any suggestions on getting this code working would be highly appreciated. I'm sure the solution is obvious but nothing I could find seemed to work.

Comment: Have you called `setHeader` over response object ?

Comment: One request sends one file.  You can't call `res.sendFile()` multiple times.  The client will request the other files and you create routes for them in your express app so when the client requests them, you will send the appropriate file matching the desired request.  You can use `express.static()` to set up route handling for all your static files with one line of code.

Comment: @jfriend00 Can you post it as an answer? It is the right answer to the question.

Comment: @GuidoGarcía - Answer posted.

Comment: Thanks four your help! I think i've got it implemented correctly, but now i'm getting a new error, the client can't seem to find my socket.io.js file on the server. I think I have it installed correctly. I have a file called node-modules in my server file with socket.io installed in it. Chrome is throwing this error: GET http://localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js   I tried pointing the index.html page directly at the socket.io.js file within node-modules but the same error is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One request sends one file. You can't call `res.sendFile()` multiple times for the same request (nor should you). If this is an HTML page that is being requested with `<script>` tags and `<style>` tags in it, then the browser will request the other files specified by those tags with separate requests.  You create routes for them in your express app so when the client requests them, you will send the appropriate file matching those desired requests.

You can use `express.static()` to set up route handling for all your static files with one line of code.

But, the key here is that `app.get('/')` is a route handler only for the HTML of the page.  The browser will then request the other resources in that page and you need routes for those resources too.  You don't just send multiple files upon one request.

Answer (score 1):

`res.sendFile()` is used to send the file located at the specified path to the client.

- A single HTTP GET request can only have one response. In Express, the `res.send()` or `res.sendFile()` method is used to send a response back to the client. Once the response is sent, the request-response cycle is complete.
- You cannot use both at a time.
- Try using `express.static()` to access these files statically by passing their relative path